# DateTime.ParseExact doesn't work as i expect

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse a DateTime (in C#) from `en-US` to `de-DE` or just in a different Format. The input DateTime is `06/17/2015 09:22:30 AM`.

What i've tried:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "d.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

or

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "d.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

in both versions i have the same output - that means the output is the same as the input, nothing has changed. I can change it in the `ToString()` method but i need it as a DateTime.

```
string test = datum.ToString("d.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
output is `17.06.2015 09:22:30`
```

Could the CurrentCultureInfo of the current Thread be the problem? Because the current Thread is set to CultureInfo `en-US`.
I've set the `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` to `de-DE` but it didn't work either.

What am i missing? I'm sure it's just a missing point in my head. If the solution is really easy - sorry for waisting time - anyway, thank you for every answer!

Comment: Does it parse correctly? I doubt because you use the wrong format for `06/17/2015 09:22:30 AM`. So the issue is not clear to me. What means _"output - output == input"_?

Comment: Sorry this textpart isn't clearly written. Just wanted to say that the output is exactly the same as the input! My fault!

Comment: `DateTime` *does not have a format*. If you want a specific format on output, it's always in the `ToString` (or `string.Format` etc.). `DateTime.ParseExact` just turns a string with a known format (note that yours is wrong) to a `DateTime`; but the `DateTime` does *not* keep the information about the format. Just use the proper `ToString` overload, e.g. `datum.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))`.

Comment: @Luaan - that was my missing point. I always thought i could change the format of the `DateTime` directly and don't have to use the `ToString()` method. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the default format of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, so you don't need to use `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string inGermanFormat = date.ToString("d.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Comment: Like Luaan said i have to do it in the `ToString()` method. I always thought i can do that directly with the `DateTime.Parse` methods. Thank you for the fast and easy answer.

Comment: @DaveStockinger: yes he is right, a `DateTime` has just a value. Internally it's basically just a single `UInt64` (unsigned 64-bit integer). So there is no format if you don't display it as string.

Comment: So the `DateTime` is calculated as `Ticks` right? Like i said before - i thought i can change the `CultureInfo` directly in the `DateTime` variable and it saves the `CultureInfo` in it. But now everything is clear and logic! Thanks again!